# Name of dynamic linker on Linux

Tags: linux, ld, dynamic-linking

On Arch-Linux when linking an object file with `ld` to a dynamically linked ELF executable, it uses `/lib/ld64.so.1` as the default dynamic linker. However, my dynamic linker is `/lib/ld-2.26.so` from Glibc.
I know, that I can specify the dynamic linker to `ld` with the `--dynamic-linker` option, but how can I ensure, that when compiling for other Linux distributions, the correct dynamic linker is found. In other words: how can I find the correct name of the dynamic linker on Linux?

Comment: would `ls --version` do the job for you?

Comment: Nope, `ls` is not part of Glibc. I could probably check for the glibc version, and assuming, that the linker has always the name `/lib/ld-<glibc version>.so`, but this requires, that I assume, that Glibc is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link with `gcc -nostartfiles` or `gcc -nostdlib` instead of using `ld` directly.
(With `-no-pie` or `-pie` if you want to make that choice explicit).

The system gcc knows the right path for the ELF interpreter.

Or to find out what the right path is, `file /bin/ls` and parse the output.  On my Arch Linux system, it includes `... dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,`

Other programs include `readelf -p /bin/ls`, and `ldd /bin/ls` also includes the right path.

(But note that `ldd` includes the right path even if you use it on an ELF executable that has the wrong path; `/bin/ldd` is a shell script that works by running the ELF interpreter on an executable with special args, so the shell script contains paths to try, and the runtime dynamic linker doesn't look for itself because it's already running.  You can use `file` or `readelf -a` to inspect executables to check for the right path, but not `ldd`.)

Comment: The first recipe is best: deferring to the compiler driver (`gcc`) naturally supports cross-compiling: see `gcc -dumpspecs` how it selects the dynamic linker depending on target.